# Wordpress posts loop pagination - first page return 125 posts instead of 10 and the rest return 10

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to show 10 posts per page with pagination on WordPress and the first page return 125 posts instead of 10 and the rest of the pages return 10 posts as requested, please assist :)

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$output = array();
global $post;
$args = array('nopaging' => false, 'paged' => $paged, 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'post_type' => 'post', 'order'=> 'DES', 'orderby' => 'date');
$postslist = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $postslist->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $postslist->have_posts() ) : $postslist->the_post(); 

    array_push($output, array("timestamp" => get_the_date('U'),"img_url" => get_the_post_thumbnail_url(), "title" => get_the_title(), "text" => get_the_content()));
         endwhile;  

        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sticky posts was the problem, I have excluded the sticky_posts from the query, and it fixed the problem

```
'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code which you can use for the pagination:

```
<?php
            /**
             * Looping through the content
             */
            $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
            $loop = new WP_Query (array(
                            'post_type' => 'custom_portfolio',
                            'orderby' => 'post_id',
                            'posts_per_page' => 10,
                            'paged' => $paged,
                            'order' => 'DESC'
                        )); ?>
            <?php while ($loop -> have_posts()) : $loop -> the_post(); ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?><?php wp_reset_query(); ?><?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

And here is the part for the pagination:

```
<!-- Pagination -->
            <div class="pagination">
                <?php
                echo paginate_links( array(
                    'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
                    'total'        => $loop->max_num_pages,
                    'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
                    'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
                    'show_all'     => false,
                    'type'         => 'plain',
                    'end_size'     => 2,
                    'mid_size'     => 1,
                    'prev_next'    => true,
                    'prev_text'    => sprintf( '<i></i> %1$s', __( 'Previous Page', 'text-domain' ) ),
                    'next_text'    => sprintf( '%1$s <i></i>', __( 'Next Page', 'text-domain' ) ),
                    'add_args'     => false,
                    'add_fragment' => '',
                ) );
                ?>
            </div>
```

Here is a good start for you, just adopt as you want.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, I don't need a pages buttons

Comment: @Orts As I said, you need to adopt a bit, I can not give you end to end solution. Check now, I've edited my code a bit.